# Dealing with compile error "illegal start of expression"

Tags: java

```
 public class PhoneNumber {

 private int areacode;

 private int number;

 private int ext;

 //intitialize data field


PhoneNumber() {

int areacode=0;

int number=0;

int ext=0;
//if no arguements are given set all identifiers to 0

}







PhoneNumber(int number) {

int areacode=0;

int ext=0;
//if number arguement is given initialize it caller value and set ext and areacode to 0
}



PhoneNumber(int newarea,int newnumber,int newext) {


//initialize all identifiers to value passed by caller
 }


PhoneNumber(String newnumber) {
//implement if caller provides String value

String str[]=newnumber.split("-");
//split string at point when - symbol is seen

str[0]=newnumber.substring(0,4);
//set str[0] to first 3 charchters of String

str[1]=newnumber.substring(5,12);
//set str[1] to last 6 charchters of string

int areacode=Interger.parseInt(str[0]);
//convert str[0] to interger and set value equal to areacode

String tempstring;
// creat string called tempstring

for (int i=0;i<str[1].length;i++) {
//if i is less than length of str[1] continue loop

if (str[1].charAT(i).matches("1"||"2"||"3"||"4"||"5"||"6"||"7"||

"8"||"9"||"0"||'A'||'B'||'C'||'D'||'E'||'F'||'H'||

'I'||'J'||'K'||'L'||'M'||'N'||'O'||'P'||'Q'||'R'||'S'||

'T'||'U'||'V'||'W'||'X'||'Y'||'Z'))
//if charchter identified at a point on str[1] is either a capital letter or digit go into if    statement
  {if (str[1].charAT(i).matches("1"||"2"||"3"||"4"||"5"||"6"||"7"||

   "8"||"9"||"0"))
  //(nested if statement)check to see if character i is a digit
  {tempstring=tempstring.concat(str[1].charAT(i));}
  //if i is a digit append it to end of tempstring

  else {tempstring=tempstring+decode(str[1].charAT(i));
    //if not invoke decode method then append to tempstring

   }}

   else {Sytem.out.println("error restart program with new input");}

   int number=Interger.parseInt(tempstring);
   //if charchter is not a letter or digit show error message
     }















 //method converts from letter to number

 private String decode(char c) {

 switch (c){

 case 'A': case 'B': case'C': return"2";

 case 'D': case 'E': case 'F': return"3";

 case 'G': case 'H': case 'I': return"4";

 case 'J': case 'K': case 'L': return"5";

 case 'M': case 'N': case 'O': return"6";

 case 'P': case 'Q': case 'R':case 'S': return"7";

 case 'T': case 'U': case'V': return"8";

 case 'W': case 'X': case'Y': case'Z': return"9";
 // given a certain capitial letter converts to number


 default: return"";
 //default value returns empty string

 }

 }



 public boolean equals(PhoneNumber pn) {
 //reade another phone number passed by called

 return this.areacode==pn.areacode && this.number==pn.number && this.ext==pn.ext;
 //if phonenumber is identical to previous number show true if not show false
 }



 public String toString() {
 //convert number to string

 String number4=new String.valueOf(PhoneNumber pn);

 String newnumber[]=number4.split("-");


 }

 }

 }
```

errors:
PhoneNumber.java:46: error: illegal start of expression
private String decode(char c) {
^

PhoneNumber.java:46: error: ';' expected
private String decode(char c) {
                     ^

PhoneNumber.java:46: error: ';' expected
private String decode(char c) {
                            ^

PhoneNumber.java:60: error: illegal start of expression
public boolean equals(PhoneNumber pn) {
^

PhoneNumber.java:60: error: ';' expected
public boolean equals(PhoneNumber pn) {
                     ^

PhoneNumber.java:60: error: ';' expected
public boolean equals(PhoneNumber pn) {
                                    ^

PhoneNumber.java:63: error: illegal start of expression
public String toString() {
^

PhoneNumber.java:63: error: ';' expected
public String toString() {
                      ^

PhoneNumber.java:64: error: ')' expected
String number4=new String.valueOf(PhoneNumber pn);
                                             ^

PhoneNumber.java:64: error: illegal start of expression
String number4=new String.valueOf(PhoneNumber pn);
                                                ^

I got it down from about 30 errors but Im not really sure how to address the "illegal start of expression" error. also if you see anything wrong with the code in general be free to point it out.
Thanks

Comment: talking about issue(s) with curly braces

Comment: Please look at your post, and ask yourself whether that's how *you* would like to see the code if you were trying to help someone. If you're unwilling to put effort into asking the question well, why would you expect anyone else to put effort into answering it?

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with this code, but i'll try to name the issues.
After pasting it into Eclipse, all errors are easily visible.

First of all, your method calls are written wrong:

```
         Error                            Correction

Lines 58, 89: Interger.parseInt(str[0]);  -->  Integer.parseInt(str[0]);

Line  64: str[1].length                   -->  str[1].length()

Lines 67, 75, 79, 82:
          charAT                          -->  charAt

Lines 67, 75:
          charAt(i).matches               -->  charAt(i) == '1' || charAt(i) == '2' || ... (not recommended)
```

Note: Try the following:

```
char c = str[1].charAt(i);
boolean b = Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isUpperCase(c) || Character.isDigit(c);
if(b) { ... }
```

Furthermore, there is no String.concat() with char:

```
Line 79: tempstring=tempstring.concat(str[1].charAt(i));  -->  tempstring += str[1].charAt(i)

Line 87: Sytem.out.println               -->  System.out.println
```

After Line 91 there is a `}` missing, which is too much in Line 157. That's where your `illegal start of expression` comes from.

Also you should redo your `toString()` method. After all this, your code should compile I think.

**Addendum :** Please, please format your code properly. It is so hard to read. As a positive side-effect you will see problems, that cause your mentioned error, earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple issues as the error messages suggest. Here are a few of them in no particular order :

1) The constructor `PhoneNumber(String newnumber)` is not closed with a curly brace `}` which should go somewhere after the lines

```
  //if charchter is not a letter or digit show error message
 }
```

2) `String` does not have a public member `length`. Instead use the method `length()` to get the length of a string.

3) `String` does not have a `charAT(int)` method. It is instead spelled `charAt(int)`

4) Neither `char` nor `Character` define a `matches(...)` method. If you want to check whether or not a character is a digit or a number you can use a combination of

```
Character.isDigit(char)
Character.isLetter(char)
Character.isLetterOrDigit(char)
Character.isUpperCase(char)
...
```

5) `Interger` should be spelled `Integer`

There are probably many more issues here that are hard to find because your code doesn't even compile but this should get you started.

Also, I would suggest formatting your code properly. That way it is much easier to find missing brackets and other such trivial mistakes. You can also use an IDE like Eclipse, Netbeans, or IntelliJ to help you debug your code as you write it. All of these IDEs also have an auto code formatting tool that might help you.